# Read to CSV Parser Error, Workers when I resave

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a CSV to a pandas df. I get an error when I do this. However, if I open the csv in excel and do a save as with a new name, it works flawlessly. I can't do this every time, but if I can write code to do it, that would work for me.

```
for file in os.listdir(downloadsdir):
    if 'SalesByInvoiceType' in file:
        file = os.path.join(downloadsdir, file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=',')
```

Error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 11, saw 15
```

I changed my code to include some read_csv parameters

```
for file in os.listdir(downloadsdir):
    if 'SalesByInvoiceType' in file:
        file = os.path.join(downloadsdir, file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding ='cp1252', sep='delimiter', header=None)

df
```

output from above statement

```
    0
0   "Set. Officer","Case #"...
1   
2   "TJ Stephens","10043","...
3   
4   "Lindsay Anderson","103...
5   
6   "Fred T. Rogers","10460...
7   
8   "Fred T. Rogers","10484...
```

when I try to grab one of the rows with

```
df[0][0]
```

the output is

```
'"\x00S\x00e\x00t\x00.\x00 \x00O\x00f\x00f\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00r\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00C\x00a\x00s\x00e\x00 \x00#\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00o\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00I\x00n\x00v\x00o\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00 \x00G\x00r\x00o\x00u\x00p\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00Q\x00u\x00a\x00n\x00t\x00i\x00t\x00y\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00U\x00n\x00i\x00t\x00 \x00P\x00r\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00A\x00m\x00o\x00u\x00n\x00t\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00C\x00l\x00i\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00 \x00S\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00u\x00s\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00D\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00D\x00e\x00s\x00c\x00r\x00i\x00p\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00T\x00e\x00a\x00m\x00 \x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00C\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00B\x00y\x00"\x00,\x00"\x00i\x00n\x00v\x00o\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00C\x00r\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00B\x00y\x00"\x00'
```

Instead of what is seen when I just pass the df.

Comment: Great question, was having this exact problem. Thoughts?